Serilog sink specifc filtering
I have this serilog conifg


"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console"
    },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "C:/Temp/logs/my.log",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "configureLogger": {
          "Filter": [
            {
              "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
              "Args": {
                "expression": "LogCategory is not null"
              }
            }
          ]
         },
          "connectionString": "Server=myServer;Database=myDB;User ID=userId;Password=pwd;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True",
          "tableName": "telemetry_logs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Level", "Exception", "Properties" ],
            "customColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "route",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 100
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "caller",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 100
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "username",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 100
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "role",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 100
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "processing_time",
                "DataType": "int"
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "api_response_message",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 250
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "useragent",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 250
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "api_response_code",
                "DataType": "char",
                "DataLength": 3
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "http_response_code",
                "DataType": "int"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "LogCategory is not null"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
},



Here is my config and logger setup


var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

// Configure Serilog
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .MinimumLevel.Information()  
    .CreateLogger();



Here is the code that I want it to log
    var dbLogger = Log.ForContext("LogCategory", "Telemetry")
        .ForContext("route", path)
        .ForContext("caller", caller)
        .ForContext("username", username)
        .ForContext("role", role)
        .ForContext("processing_time", processingTime)
        .ForContext("api_response_message", apiResponseMessage)
        .ForContext("api_response_code", apiResponseCode)
        .ForContext("useragent", userAgent);

    dbLogger.Information("API telemetry");

Serilog creates the table, removes standard columns as per config, add new columns, but it logs everything including the code above. I want it to exclude everything but the above in MSSqlServer sink. Please note I have filter in 2 places, I am not sure which one is the correct place to put it.

I have tried @p['LogCategory'] is not null

also have used @m for filtering by message

Filter on sink level only work on sub-logger, this fixed it
{
  "Name": "Logger",
  "Args": {
    "configureLogger": {
      "Filter": [
        {
          "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
          "Args": {
            "expression": "Contains(@m,'telemetry')"
          }
        }
      ],
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "MSSqlServer",
          "Args": {

